# Angular - Cannot get current user's role in guard to check if the he/she has permission to access protected routes

Tags: angular, observable, rbac, behaviorsubject, angular-guards

I am trying to implement **role based access control** on `Angular` based project where there are multiple types of roles

I want to get user's data(role property) in `CanActivate` interface to check if the user has permission to access protected `routes` in `guard`, but `BehaviouralSubject` does not updating initial state after receiving latest values from `API`.

Thus I am getting user's data in authentification service, 
then passing received value to `userRole` subject, but updated property (BehaviouralSubject) 
is not available in guard file.

**Authentification Service**

```js
    constructor() {
      let localToken: string
      if (localStorage.getItem('token')) {
        localToken = localStorage.getItem('token')
        this.getUserInfo(localToken)
      }
    }
      userRole = new BehaviorSubject(null)
      userRole$ = this.userRole.asObservable()    

      // called in constructor of a auth. service (every time when user called) 
      // and after login as well, so user's data always available. 
      getUserInfo(data) {
          this.requestService
            .post('GET_USER_INFO', data)
            .subscribe((response: ILoggedInUser) => {
               // data from API {email: "test@test.com", userName: "ccc", role: "viewer"}
               this.userRole.next(response.user)  
            })
        }
```

**Auth Guard**

```js
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

      return this.authService.userRole$.pipe(
        map(member => {
          if (member) {
            // check if route is restricted by role
            if (
              route.data.roles &&
              route.data.roles.indexOf(member.role) === -1
            ) {
              // role not authorised so redirect to home page
              this.router.navigate(['/login'])
              return false
            }

          return true
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login'])
            return false
          }
        }),
      )
    }
```

Here is **routing**:

```js
     const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'home',
        component: HomeComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: ['admin'] },
      },
      {
        path: 'editor',
        component: EditorsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: ['admin', 'editor'}
      },
      {
        path: 'viewer',
        component: ViewersComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        data: { roles: ['admin', 'viewer'] },
      }
    ]
```

I tried another approach as well, (for example using Subscriptions) but when I try to `subscribe` to `userRole` subject like this:

```js
     return this.authService.userRole.subscribe((member) => {
        .......
        ....... 
     }
```

then there is a 
**Property 'canActivate' in type 'AuthGuard' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'CanActivate'** error,
since `Subscription` type is not assignable to type `boolean`.

Therefore, could you give any hint OR recommend the better way of handling **RBAC** in `angular` with observables.

P.S.

I have seen [solutions](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-role-based-authorization-example) with `localStorage`, but I don't want to keep user's data (except token) there.

Comment: What's the specific problem? Is there part of your solution thar isn't working, or are you just seeking general advice?

Comment: I think both. I am not able to receive user's data in guard file, since BehaviourSubject not updating value, hence am I doing something wrong? or is there any better approach?

Comment: `canActivate` could be tidied up, but I'm not sure that's the cause of your problem. How does `getUserInfo` get called?

Comment: `getUserInfo` called in constructor of a auth. service (every time when user called) and after login as well. I will update the question now.

Comment: I still don't see how `getUserInfo` gets called?

Comment: Just added constructor() in Aauthentification service (at the top of question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209307/discussion-between-johannesmatevosyan-and-kurt-hamilton).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `userRole$` observable emmits `null` initially because it is subscribed to userRole `BehaviorSubject` which gets null as an argument.

Hence, userRole$ observable is equal to null getting an update  and property canActivate in type AuthGuard cannot return null.

Therefore you should use filter() operator before passing object to map in order to get rid of null.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
  return this.authService.userRole$.pipe(
    filter(member => !!member),  // Filter NULL value here before sending object further
        map(member => {
        ....
      return true

      } else {
        ....
      }
    )
}
```